# C#: Generic method doesn't call specific method overload

Tags: c#, generics, mono, unity-game-engine, polymorphism

I am trying to create a generic method in C#, which will call different methods based on the argument datatype in its body and process their result afterwards. I am trying to achieve this by creating a generic wrapper method and then provide several overloads of the processing method - including a generic one that'll be used if no specific overload is available.

When I call the processing method directly, appropriate version is correctly selected. However when I call it from the wrapper method it always selects the generic one, even if there's a matching overload for the specific datatype I passed to it.

Is there any way to adjust the code to make it behave the way I need to? Or do I have to use a different approach.

I need the code to be compatible with Mono 2.6.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Func<T>(T val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Func");
    }

    static void Func(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int Func");
    }

    static void Func(string val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String Func");
    }

    static void FuncWrap<T>(T val)
    {
        Console.Write("Wrap: ");
        Func(val);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func(2);
        Func("Potato");
        Func(2.0);

        FuncWrap(2);
        FuncWrap("Potato");
        FuncWrap(2.0);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could have FuncWrap overloads that take an int and string as well (or just use Func methods directly without wrapping).

Answer (score 15):

> Is there any way correct this behavior?

It's already the correct behaviour according to the C# language specification. The overload of `Func` called within `FuncWrap` is normally determined *at compile time*, so it can't pick a different `Func` overload based on the execution-time type.

One way of changing the behaviour, however, is to use dynamic typing:

```
static void FuncWrap<T>(T val)
{
    Console.Write("Wrap: ");
    dynamic x = val;
    Func(x);
}
```

That will now perform overload resolution at execution time based on the *actual* type of the value of `x`. This incurs a performance cost, but should do what you want it to.

Alternatively, you could hard-code knowledge of the overloads:

```
static void FuncWrap<T>(T val)
{
    Console.Write("Wrap: ");
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        Func((string)(object)val);
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        Func((int)(object)val);
    }
    else
    {
        Func(val);
    }
}
```

That's clearly pretty horrible though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word it correctly. I meant "correct" as in make it behave the way I need to.

The dynamic doesn't seem to work with Mono 2.6 (I'm using the code in the Unity engine).

Yeah, the second method is not desirable, I'm looking for something cleaner (and ideally faster).

Comment: @TomFrooxiusMariank: Looking at the release notes for Mono 2.6, it *should* be supported - it may be that Unity is actually limiting things to an older profile. (It would need the .NET 4 profile.) Without `dynamic`, you'd probably be best off with the hack at the end of my answer... that's going to perform reasonably well (better than dynamic, which is basically using reflection). You could use reflection yourself of course, but that won't be fast. If none of these is suitable, you should probably consider a redesign.

Comment: I see, I'm probably out of luck with current Unity version of Unity now then, I'll check if I can change the profile somehow, but I'm not sure if that won't have some undesired consequences.

If it won't work, I'll probably rework the code to avoid need for this feature. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomFrooxiusMariank if you can't use dunamic and don't want to make lots of ifs, you can use my class that I've prepared for other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662637/return-instance-using-reflection-in-c-sharp/25663380#25663380. It allows you to determine cases with fluent api. You can adapt my answer. I'm preparing library, so you can wait for it, if it fits your requirements. Sample: `obj.StronglyInvoke().When<int>(Func).When<string>(Func).Invoke();`